# generate graph from .eps file (preferably using R)

Tags: r

Using the R package 'Deducer', I saved a graphic (chart) as an .eps file.

I can open the .eps file, it's just a bunch of text.

How do I re-generate the graphic (chart) from the .eps file (preferably using Deducer or R)?

Comment: What kind of a graphic is it, a chart? What do you mean by "regenerate"; run a series of commands that duplicates the EPS file? I want to make sure you don't want to merely load it.

Comment: @Emre It's a chart. Yes, I can re-create the graphic chart using the same commands that originally created it. But I was wondering what my options were if I only had the .eps file and needed to see what the chart looked like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPS is "Encapsulated PostScript". Its meant for embedding like an image in documents, or sending to printers. You can view it with a PostScript document viewer, and there are free PostScript document viewers for Linux, Windows, and Mac OSs. Ghostview, Evince, etc etc.

So although you can view the graphic once you've got a PostScript document viewer, you cannot load it into R as if you had just plotted it.

Comment: Furthermore, if the EPS format is a problem, any Linux system comes with an `eps2pdf` command to convert it to PDF.